# UIButton in a subClass of UIViewController not respond to any touches

Tags: events, uibutton, subclass, touches

I have met the problem some days ago,I also have searched the solutions everywhere,but none work fine.I add a button into a custom viewController(is a subClass of UIViewController),then,add the customView into myMainViewController.
code like this:

```
customView.h
cusomView:UIViewController
{
UIButton *myButton;
}

-(void)doSomething:(id)sender;

customView.m
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view=[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,100,100);
  //init the button....
  [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)     forControlEvents:...upInside];
  [self.view addSubViews:myButton];
}
-(void)doSomething:(id)sender
{
.......
}


myMainViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   ......
   customView *cusView=[customView alloc] init];
   [self.view addSubViews:cusView];
}
```

just so,It display well,But the button do not repond to any touches.Could you help me?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't adding the uibutton to the `myMainController` directly?